# How can I reverse selector combination in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the current project I use to two html tags. The second one is hidden by default. If you hover the first one the second one will appear. If you head over the the second now visible one it stays open.

```css
#button{
  background:#050;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#button{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#button:hover{
  color:#ff4;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#subfield{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background:#777;
}

#button + #subfield{
  display:none;
}

#button:hover + #subfield{
  display:block;
}

#button + #subfield:hover{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">Menu Button</div>
<div id="subfield"></div>
```

That works fine. But the first html tag has a hover effect itself. How can I keep this hover effekt while heading over to the other html tag?

Comment: Relevant code **should be in question**. Do not work around the quality check by formatting link as code block.

Comment: I still don't get how to use jsfiddle right in Stackoverflow. It is not realy straight forward. Paste that stuff in to the post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Comment: @Pete It is better than JSBin and JSFiddle. Just paste the HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Similar to JSFiddle. `:)` Check my answer for a solution.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani That helps like how a stone helps you with iPhone installation! `:P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a parent selector or previous selector in CSS. Simple fix, give `:hover` for the parent of the two:

1. Give a parent `div`.
2. Apply `display: inline-block`.
3. Give the `:hover` to the parent, instead of the `button`.

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-block;
}
#button {
  background: #050;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#button {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#parent:hover #button {
  color: #ff4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#subfield {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #777;
}
#button + #subfield {
  display: none;
}
#button:hover + #subfield {
  display: block;
}
#button + #subfield:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="button">Menu Button</div>
  <div id="subfield"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like what I was searching for

Comment: I did ... stackoverflow deter the users from accept in the first 2 min ;)

Comment: @Pete It is 15 min gap. `:D`

Comment: Don't get why this was downvoted when it's a fine working solution. (Although not sure why `display: inline-block` is needed?)

Comment: @JordanGray That wraps the whole thing, with the same width as the contents. So the hover is not active above the range.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Aaah, gotcha! Nice.